# ActionBar.getSelectedTab() value?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

So I have the following code

```
ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
Tab s = ab.getSelectedTab();
Log.i("***DEBUG***", "I'm in: " + s);
```

which returns

```
***DEBUG*** I'm in: com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl@40cdd548
```

where as I would like it to return a `String` or an `int` value like "Assets Tab" or even "1".

I'm sure there is a very simple explanation yet I couldn't find it here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

or here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html

or anywhere on these forums

So I come to you good folks and ask, how do i return an index int value, or a string value for this simple statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
Tab s = ab.getSelectedTab();
Log.i("***DEBUG***", "I'm in: " + s.getText().toString());
```

Comment: thank you very much my friend, you were first so I will accept your answer

Answer (score 3):

The [`Tab`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html) class has a `getText()` method and a `getPosition()` method. The former will get the actual text of the tab and the latter will get it's position (as an int) in the ActionBar.

Comment: thank you very much my friend, I upvoted your answer, there was another before you though so I'm accepting his answer as they are both correct

Answer (score 1):

```
ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar()
int s = ab.getSelectedTab().getPosition();
//getPosition: Current position, or INVALID_POSITION if this tab is not currently in the action bar.
Log.i("***DEBUG***", "I'm in: " + s);
```